# Power BI accessing blob storage, files headers are not there

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am a beginner in this so any advice is helpful. I used azure synapse analytics to get information from an API and save this as files in my blob storage. When using the online web application, the files do have headers however when I connect my Power BI to my blob storage and accessing the file on that, there are no headers.

[Azure Synapse Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8uSe.png)

[PowerBI Accessing same file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rh12.png)

I went into the pipeline and made sure the files are saving with "First row as header" and that didn't make an effect on my power BI query.

[First row as header option ticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5xWw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have many columns?

You can manually name columns in Power BI by editing the query. Double-click on the column name or select "Rename" from the Transform tab.

If you do have lots of columns that is probably a lot of work.

You want the files to come through with the headers as the first row in the table. Try unselecting "first row of headers" and then once you have your data source, go to transform data and select "Use first row as headers".

https://pbivisuals.com/2021/03/20/how-to-use-first-row-as-headers-in-power-query/